# Is there a term for this kind of figure? Can it be produced for any n?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, terminology

The Nature Genetics article [The draft genome of tropical fruit durian (Durio zibethinus)](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/ng.3972.html?foxtrotcallback=true) (open access pdf!) includes an interesting diagram in Figure 2. Figure 2a shows the sharing of genes between five species using a diagram with five-fold rotational symmetry where each wedge includes all possible overlap combinations with the other four. The number of shared genes for each of the 31 possible combinations is shown.

I'd like to ask if there is a term for this kind of figure in Mathematics, if it can be produced in two dimensions for any number $n$, and if there are patterns which are not topologically n-fold symmetric - in other words patterns that can not be reshaped topologically so that they are just an n-fold rotational repeat of a single identical wedges shape as this one is?

[image]

> Figure 2(a): Sharing of gene families by durian and three other Malvales plants, with A. thaliana as an outgroup. The number in parentheses indicates durian-specific gene families among all 11 plants considered.

*Who would have thought that Durian is closely related to* Cacao!? See also the BBCs [Singapore scientists reveal origins of durian's pungent aroma](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-41563300)

Comment: Need help with proper tagging.

Comment: Maybe of interest: [The Search for Simple Symmetric Venn Diagrams](http://www.ams.org/notices/200611/ea-wagon.pdf) by Ruskey, Savage & Wagon.

Comment: @HansLundmark thank you for the link - this is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for. An indirect way to show that 5 is prime :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).  The diagram you cite seems to be a (nonconvex) variant of [Branko Grünbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branko_Gr%C3%BCnbaum)'s 5-set rotationally symmetric Venn diagram.  (The single-component regions here are convex, but this is not the case in the diagram you cite.)

[image]

Venn gave an iterative construction allowing any number of sets in the plane.  These [diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets) are very asymmetric -- i.e. not rotationed and slightly translated copies of a single shape.  There are also [pseudo-symmetric Venn diagrams](http://www.combinatorics.org/files/Surveys/ds5/VennSymmVariants.html), where the *diagram* has rotational symmetry, but the single-component regions are not congruent.  I recall an article on rectilinear Venn diagrams for any number of regions (about, hmm..., 20 years ago), but don't seem to be having any luck digging up a reference.

Comment: [This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467112/#comment5097556_2467112) is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets); Wikipedia shows several shapes for larger numbers of sets.

This particular shape is a variant on an elliptical form first described by Branko Grünbaum; most other set sizes seem to not have symmetrical versions.  The common generalized ones - Venn's edge-following method, and Edwards' sphere projection method - are not symmetric.

Comment: In the spirit of avoiding a link-only answer, could you address the question as asked in full here? Also, could this not also be an Euler diagram as well?

Comment: Thank you, looks better!

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that this is an Euler diagram, as it shows the real world relations rather than all possible (theoretical) relations, which a strict Venn must show. To be a Venn, would it not need to be completely boxed with the space outside the interlocking shapes but inside the box representing plants that fall into none of the categories?